# Send data from php to java

Tags: java, php, bukkit

I have found quite a lot of other posts on this topic but none seem to have the answer I need.
I have written a Bukkit plugin for Minecraft that can send post data to a PHP page and get a return from the page.

Now the one thing I can't figure out. I would like to have a button on the page, and when the button is clicked, send data to the Java plugin and have the plugin print the message.

I have seen something about sockets. But after reading about them  I can't figure out how to set them up.
Pretty much at any time you should be able to click the button and it sends data to the Java plugin and I can use that data however I like.

Does anyone know how I can have the Java plugin constantly waiting for data from the page?

My current code:
(This sends the players name to the website.)

```
String re = "";  
URL url = new URL("address here");  
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();  
con.setDoOutput(true);  
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());  
ps.print("player=" + player.getName());  
con.getInputStream();  
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));  
String line;  
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {  
   re += line + "\n";  
}  
rd.close();  
ps.close();
```

And my php just returns any post data it gets.
It works fine, but I would like to listen in my java plugin for data from the php page.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make communication between two servers. I'd use one of them:

- Sockets
- JMS - Java Message Service such as ActiveMQ

Both of them have tutorials available, just google.

Comment: Yes, I heard about sockets. And I am trying to figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `database`, or setup a `json/xml` api on the `PHP` end, and access the `database`, or access the `json/xml` from Java with this example code to open the url.

```
URL url = new URL("site.com/api/foo.json");

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

You can look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm) to parse JSON with Java.

Comment: So you say I should write to a file with Java and read it with PHP and write a file with PHP and read it with Java? I think that would only work one way because the PHP can't access files where the Java is running.

Comment: @ParkerJones Generate the `JSON` from a database in PHP, and read it from Java. Write from Java using an api in PHP. It's pretty complicated, but doable. The simplest way is to use a database.